# double quotas appearing after json output in PHP array to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, double-quotes

I have read a question answer at

[PHP Array to json, how to get rid of some double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012695/php-array-to-json-how-to-get-rid-of-some-double-quotes)

I have same issue but my code is little different so I unable to ride of rid of some double quotes.

My code :

```
$features = array();
$geojson = array(
    'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features'  => $features
 );
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$type = $row['type'];
if($type == 'Point')
    {
        //$output = ;
            $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
         'properties' => array(
             'score' => "",
             'fid' => ""
        //Other fields here, end without a comma
            ),

      'geometry' => array(
        'type' => $type,
        'coordinates' => array($row['lat'], $row['lng'])
            )
        );
    }
else {
//$output = '['.$row['more_info'].']';
$feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
         'properties' => array(
             'score' => "",
             'fid' => ""
        //Other fields here, end without a comma
            ),

      'geometry' => array(
        'type' => $type,
        'coordinates' => array('['.$row['more_info'].']')
            )
        );
}

    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
};
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo $newgeojson =  json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

array Output before convert to json (json_encode):

```
Array
(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [score] => 
                            [fid] => 
                        )

                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Point
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 88.388786315918
                                    [1] => 22.551879205144
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [score] => 
                            [fid] => 
                        )

                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Polygon
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => [[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726]]
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Output I am getting after json_encode

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"score":"","fid":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[88.388786315918,22.551879205144]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"score":"","fid":""},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":["[[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726]]"]}}]}
```

As you can see the coordinates coming with " ".

```
"[[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726]]"
```

I do not want that double quote start and end of multi coordinates.

Please guide / suggest me how can I ride of those double quote.

Comment: $output = [".$row['more_info']."];.i think this might be wrong quote outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `'coordinates' => array('['.$row['more_info'].']')`.

I don't know why you are adding `'['` and `']'` here, but it looks like you're trying to build the JSON string manually. If you do that, then yes, you will end up with unwanted quotes when you use `json_encode()` because `json_encode()` treats the entire contents as a string.

It's not clear what `$row['more_info']` contains to start with, but I guess it contains a string that is already in JSON format. If you want to add this to your output JSON, then the first thing you need to do is convert it back into a PHP array.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
'coordinates' => json_decode($row['more_info'], true)
```

Comment: $row['more_info'] is contanning polygon value 

<code>[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726]<code>

Comment: okay, so you need to drop the `<code>` and `</code>`, and then to the `json_decode()` as per the answer.

Comment: No, I only need to it to print exact it was  
[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726] 
With [ ] before after as it output [[88.41796875, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.572804222704],[88.41796875, 22.577876475976],[88.428955078125, 22.578114233267],[88.428955078125, 22.573121244003],[88.428611755371, 22.568048815726],[88.41796875, 22.568048815726]]
But I do not want Double quotation before and after

Comment: <code> and </code> is nothing, I put it to show output only

Comment: Use backtick characters to show code like that on this site.  :)

Comment: Okay, so if `$row['more_info']` contains all of that as a string, then yes, the answer is to do a json_decode() on it when adding it to the array. That will mean it should come out correct when you do the `json_encode()` at the end of the program.

Comment: you Right. I decode it to array then encode which solve my problem. Many Many thanks you are rally great. 

 $output = json_decode('['.$row['more_info'].']');
$feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
         'properties' => array(
             'score' => "",
             'fid' => ""
        //Other fields here, end without a comma
            ),

      'geometry' => array(
        'type' => $type,
        'coordinates' => array($output)
            )
        );

Answer (score 0):

@Simba - Thank you for guide me. Your guides help me to get exact result

```
$output = json_decode('['.$row['more_info'].']');
$feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
         'properties' => array(
             'score' => "",
             'fid' => ""
        //Other fields here, end without a comma
            ),

      'geometry' => array(
        'type' => $type,
        'coordinates' => array($output)
            )
        );
```

Comment: Relax, there's only one negative vote. Maybe you just caught someone having a bad day. But complaining about it usually makes things worse.